# NullPointerException in Android Studio 3 Beta 1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have updated to Android Studio from Canary 9 to Beta 1 and I got this error when open my project.

I have invalidate cache and restart but not lucky.

My gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(UnixPath.java:77)   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.(UnixPath.java:71)  at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)    at
>   java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)    at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutput.getOutputPath(BuildOutput.java:222)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.lambda$load$2(BuildOutputs.java:243)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>     at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:245)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:184)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildOutputs.load(BuildOutputs.java:140)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.lambda$get$1(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:55)
>     at
>   com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.forEach(ImmutableList.java:397)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:50)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.BuildOutputsSupplier.get(BuildOutputsSupplier.java:35)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.AndroidArtifactImpl.getOutputs(AndroidArtifactImpl.java:134)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$ReflectionMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:592)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$AdaptingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:397)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$PropertyCachingMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:625)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SafeMethodInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:647)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$SupportedPropertyInvoker.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:670)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.adapter.ProtocolToModelAdapter$InvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(ProtocolToModelAdapter.java:356)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202.getOutputs(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.(IdeAndroidArtifactImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.lambda$new$0(IdeVariantImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
>     at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeVariantImpl.(IdeVariantImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.lambda$new$4(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.lambda$computeIfAbsent$0(ModelCache.java:31)
>     at java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1126)     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.ModelCache.computeIfAbsent(ModelCache.java:31)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeModel.copy(IdeModel.java:74)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:87)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.ide.android.IdeAndroidProjectImpl.(IdeAndroidProjectImpl.java:68)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.AndroidModuleModel.(AndroidModuleModel.java:131)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleContentRoots(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:214)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.populateModuleContentRoots(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:103)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:366)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:902)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:886)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:218)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:139)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:66)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:139)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:125)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:388)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:445)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:137)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: delete your build folders and try again.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs works! Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete Build folders and try again